# Do child actors also improvise their roles in Curb Your Enthusiasm?

Tags: curb-your-enthusiasm

Curb is famous for having all the actors improvise their roles. But does this also apply to the child actors on the show? For example, it would be very impressive if [this scene](https://youtu.be/qYVK_OqyUzk) was improvised.